# how to execute the same init code on each controller instantiated by $routeProvider?

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

In my .config I have a router that instantiate a pair `controller-router`:

```
angular.module('reporting', ['ng', 'ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'reporting.directives', 'reporting.controllers', 'reporting.config', 'ngGrid', 'ui.bootstrap'])
    .config(["$routeProvider", "$provide", function ($routeProvider, $provide) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/dealersReq', {
                templateUrl: 'reporting/partials/dealersReqs.html',
                controller: 'DealersCtrl'
            })
            .when('/lmtReq', {
                templateUrl: 'reporting/partials/lmt.html',
                controller: 'lmtCtrl'
            })
            .when('/leadsCreated', {
                templateUrl: 'reporting/partials/leadsCreated.html',
                controller: 'LeadsCreatedCtrl'
            })
...
```

but each controller share the same `initialization code` (think about it like a constructor) that sets in the rootScope some variable like a title and other useful information for some controllers outside the `<view>`:

```
.controller('DealersCtrl', ['$scope','$rootScope', 'CONFIG',
    function($scope, $rootScope, CONFIG) {

        //////////// duplicated code

        var key = 'qtsldsCrtSncheQ';

        $rootScope.openReport.key = key;
        $rootScope.openReport.title = CONFIG.reports['' + key].title;

        //////////// duplicated code

        console.log('Initialized! Now I do what a controller should really do');
    }]);
```

What I would like to do is finding a way to move that code - which is duplicated into every controller at the moment - into something smarter and neater. Soemthing that the route can call during the routing instanciation for example. Of course each controller should have a different key, but that one could be exactly the controller name actually. I really don't know how to improve this. Any suggestion?

Comment: I've often felt that controllers should have a "before" function, some way that you can say, "run this code before you run any controller". In the "old" days, I used sammyjs for client-side routing, it supported a "before" function, which ran before each route's handler.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't create a method on the `$rootScope` which does that, and then call it from each controller, i.e.: `$rootScope.init()`.

Comment: what I would like to avoid is making a call in each Controller. Sooner or later I'll forget it!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Service for shared code but you should avoid to use $rootScope
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16739309/3068081

Comment: yup, I wrote $rootScope for the shake of clarity, but in actual fact there's a directive scope that encompasses everything I need

Comment: $service could do the job, yes, but I should remember to call that service in each `controller`. Not as much smart as I would like :-)

Comment: Yeah, in a past personal project I was looking something like a Controllers heritage but all the answers ended in a Service solution :S

Comment: a co-worker has suggested me a `decorator`. But he also said that "avoid it as much as you can"