# Designing app logic with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

So I am currently starting to create my first app in AngularJS and I am having a bit of trouble working out how components such as modules, factories and services should be applied for my specific app.

In the tutorials I have seen, for the sake of simplicity, the data collected via `$http` in a service is  `$scope` ready. What I mean by "scope ready" is a controller can directly call the service and place the output directly into the scope without any modification.

However, in my app, the data that will be retrieved via `$http` is in an arbitrary json format `Data1` and it needs to be converted to an arbitrary json format `Data2` before it can be placed into the `$scope`. Once converted, the data in format `Data1` is no longer required. The user then makes changes to the data (in format `Data2`) and the clicks a submit button when finished. The data is then converted back from format `Data2` back to format `Data1` and sent back to the server. This process of converting between data formats is I guess "the Brains" of my app and if I where to write it in vanilla JavaScript would require multiple functions (not sure how that translates to AngularJS though).

So my first question is, where would I place my data format conversions, forward and back? Should I put them in services, factories, modules, controllers, etc.? My guess is I would put the conversion between data formats in a service but I am not sure.

To make things a bit more complex, the data for my app only needs to be fetched once (as data format `Data1`) and then used across multiple views (as data format `Data2`). From reading [this question and its suggested answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16739084/) I think the best option is to use the `$rootScope` to store my data (in format `Data2`). So my second question is, how do I get my data into the `$rootScope` independently of any particular view so it only runs once at the initialization of the app? (I know how to complete the reverse process with the button described above).

If I haven't explained myself very well please let me know and I will try to clarify.

Thanks, JamesStewy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's just get the terminology aligned first - it might simplify things.

**Factories** and **Services** are the same things as far as controllers are concerned. The only difference is in their creation, but that happens before they are injected into the controller.

**Modules** are like packages, or containers of functionality. So, for the purposes of this question, they are of no importance.

**Models** are object representing the data (and associated functionality) of your backend's data layer.

**ViewModels** are objects used and modified by the View. This is what you referred to as "scope-ready".

**Controllers** are responsible for handling calls coming from the View (e.g. `ng-click`) and for marshaling data between Models and ViewModels (often via Services). It is a good practice to keep the controllers as lean as possible.

So this is where you need to make a judgement call. Is this conversion business-logic independent? Is this conversion specific to a single controller? Is this conversion short and readable? If the answer to the above is no, then you should place this logic in a Service. Services are used to encapsulate the backend/business logic or more-than-trivial front-end logic.

**As to your second question**, I would suggest having the Service fetch and cache the data in a local service variable. Services are singletons, so every controller will get the same instance.

```
app.service("myService", function($http){
  function myService {
     var promise = null;
     this.get = function(){ 
        if (!promise){
           promise = $http(url);
        }
        return promise;
     }
  }
});

app.controller("ctrl1", function($scope, myService){
   myService.get().then(data){
      $scope.items = data;
   }
});
```

You *could* use `$rootScope` - and store the data there within the [`.run`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#run-blocks) block. But I would only do so if this data is going to be used in the View (i.e. HTML) and by all or most of the Views. Also, be careful (!) - if the data is asynchronously fetched it would not yet be available when controllers run.

Comment: Ok, so that has cleared up my first question. It looks like a service/factory is the best option. I am still confused about the second question though so here is my updated situation. I have a service/factory which has a function `get()` which makes an async call, converts the data then returns a ViewModel. I would only like to run `get()` once when the app is initially loaded. The generated ViewModel will be used by most if not all the Views in my app. My question is where do I put the line that is along the lines of `$rootScope.data = myService.get()`? (not sure of the specifics)

Comment: Well, first of all, since it's async, you shouldn't do `$rootScope.data = myService.get()` - it won't give you what you're expecting. I'll clarify the second part in the answer shortly.

Comment: Oh yeah. Does this have to do with the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16286605/initialize-angularjs-service-with-asynchronous-data. It seems quite complex for something I thought would be pretty simple though.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily need to use `resolve`. I updated the answer