# Storing data in $rootScope

Tags: angularjs, cordova, rootscope

Is it advisable to store data in $rootScope. 
I have a cordova app which uses sensor data which is coming every 100ms. For me to use that data in multiple controller I am using $rootScope.sensorData variable which is being refreshed every 100ms. Is it alright to use it this way? Is there a better way to do it?

Thank you

Comment: This has been already discussed here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35345446/best-practice-for-using-rootscope-in-an-angularjs-application

Answer (score 2):

You can store it in factory. In AngularJS factory is singleton, so only instance is created.

```
myApp.factory('SensorSrv', function SensorSrv() {
  var sensorData;
  return {
    setData: setData,
    getData: getData
  };

  function setData(data) {
    sensorData = data;
  }

  function getData() {
    return sensorData;
  }
});
```

You can also user local-storage if you want to persist the data.

Comment: Using factory to serve data between multiple controller is the best way I know. But the data will be set every 100ms which will become a memory hogg. Implementing this effected performance even more than storing data in $rootScope.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not good idea to use **$rootScope** in entire code logic  , There are lot of reasons behind that ... Instead of that you can create code login in **services** it is more flexible ... and also you can see this link

[Best practice for using $rootscope in an Angularjs application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35345446/best-practice-for-using-rootscope-in-an-angularjs-application)

Answer (score 1):

From the Official Docs:

> ### `$rootScope` exists, but it can be used for evil
>
> Scopes in Angular form a hierarchy, prototypally inheriting from a root scope at the top of the tree. Usually this can be ignored, since most views have a controller, and therefore a scope, of their own.
>
> Occasionally there are pieces of data that you want to make global to the whole app. For these, you can inject `$rootScope` and set values on it like any other scope. Since the scopes inherit from the root scope, these values will be available to the expressions attached to directives like ng-show just like values on your local `$scope`.
>
> **Of course, global state sucks and you should use `$rootScope` sparingly,** like you would (hopefully) use with global variables in any language. In particular, don't use it for code, only data. If you're tempted to put a function on `$rootScope`, it's almost always better to put it in a service that can be injected where it's needed, and more easily tested.
>
> **Conversely, don't create a service whose only purpose in life is to store and return bits of data.**

--[AngularJS Miscellaneous FAQ](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using app.value `app.value('test', 20);`
Because by using $rootScope you are exposing that value to all the services which might be a security threat. By using **value** you can make sure where do you want to use that variable according to your requirement.