# Is this a right way to using $rootscope to store a service as a variable

Tags: angularjs

I have a function to handle logout application after user did not send request to server for a long time (it's `CommonConfig.TIME_OUT_TO_LOGOUT` in the code below). I use $rootScope to store `logOutInterval` as a variable. But I wonder that, if I used $rootScope as a right way.

- The `handleSuccess` is a function that handle request $http success.

Sorry for my bad English.

```
function handleSuccess(response) {
            $anchorScroll(); // scroll to top after load API completed
            if ($rootScope.logOutInterval) {
                console.log("Reupdate count down to logout");
                $timeout.cancel($rootScope.logOutInterval);
                $rootScope.logOutInterval = undefined;
            }
            console.log("Start count down to logout at " + new Date());
            $rootScope.logOutInterval = $timeout(function() {
                console.log("Start logout at " + new Date());
                $http({
                    method: 'get',
                    headers: defaultHeader(),
                    url: envConfig.API_HOST + CommonConfig.URI.LOG_OUT
                }).then(function() {
                    toastr.error("Token has expired");
                    PageService.logOutAction();
                });
            }, CommonConfig.TIME_OUT_TO_LOGOUT);
            return $q.resolve(response);
        }
```

Comment: I got what you are trying to say, but still not got that what is the issue that you are facing?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm a AngularJS  newbie , so I don't know how to use $rootScope as a right way (just in this situation). In the example above, is there any wrong or bad practice? is there any other way (as an alternative) to do this without using $rootScope?

Thank you again :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing data in $rootScope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38651880/storing-data-in-rootscope)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to store and share data between controllers, or something that will outlive the controller's lifecycle, the best practice is use services for that.

If you just want to store data inside a service, no need to use $rootScope for that.