# How can i get values from $stateChanges

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Please Helpme How can i get values from `$statechangeStart` and `$stateChaneSuccess`

**MyApp.js**

```
app.run(function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, options) {
          $scope.IsLoading = true;

    })
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, options) {
           $scope.IsLoading = False;
    })
})
```

**Home.js**

///Here How can i use `IsLoading`

Comment: You have to use **$rootScope** to reflect change in your application.

Comment: Don't use $rootScope, it will work but better to define your own provider

Comment: could u plz mentioned any example

Comment: yah working on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `providers` (generally a service or factory, maybe a .value) to define things that can be injected into controllers.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers

https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md

[Best practice for using $rootscope in an Angularjs application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35345446/best-practice-for-using-rootscope-in-an-angularjs-application)

```js
angular.module('myapp',[])
  .value('SharedObject', {isLoading:true})
  .run(function($timeout, SharedObject){
    $timeout(function(){SharedObject.isLoading = false}, 2000);
  })
  .controller('MyCtrl', function(SharedObject){
    this.SharedObject = SharedObject;
  })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">

  <head>
    <script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MyCtrl as myctrl">
    {{myctrl.SharedObject}}
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: @shaunhussain Thnak a lot for ur answer and suggestion

Comment: No problem thanks for considering the options, will be better off in the long run, good to know you can put things on $rootScope but just better in general to use your own special purpose services (easier to debug/manage as projects grow too and keep all shared functionality, basically everything in factories/services so you can keep it DRY [don't repeat yourself])

Answer (score 0):

Because you are adding this logic in the `run` function, you'll want to set the `isLoading` property on the `$rootScope` object, not the `$scope` object, which does not exist in this context:

```
app.run(function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, options) {
        $rootScope.isLoading = true;

    });
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, options) {
        $rootScope.isLoading = false;
    });
});
```

Then, in your template that has access to `$rootScope`, you can show a loading screen by using `ngIf`, which conditionally adds elements to the DOM:

```
<div ng-if="isLoading" class="loading-screen">
    Loading...
</div>
```

Comment: Don't think it's generally good practice to dump everything into $rootScope it becomes a global space which is a mess to manage, only use it for broadcasting events or listening for events that are broadcast on rootscope really (or applying a digest cycle in some cases but most of the time people do that when they shouldn't too)