# How to manage user details throughout all the controllers in angular Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

hello guys i wanted to know how to manage like user session id,name throught the view controllers in Angular Js.

The senario is that i did http call and get user id and name.
now i want to is use that whenever i want to in any controllers.

i tried with angular value service like setting

```
app.value("user",{user_id:"0",user_name:"blank"})
```

and http call where in a controller

```
app.controller("exampleCtrl",function($http,user){
      user.user_id = data.user_id;
      //lets say the user id is 4.
      //and now user.user_id should be 4 as well
})
```

now in another controller

```
app.controller("nextCtrl",function(user){
    console.log(user.user_id);
    //gives me 0 which should be 4?
})
```

i though it would give me 4.

I hope you got the general idea of what i am trying to do
is there another way to do things ? or am i doing it the wrong way? pLease guide me.

Thank You.

Comment: check the answer below, i have given you plunker example as well as using factory as well as sessionStorage. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there are various options for you like using:
`$sessionStorage`, `localStorage`, `appConstant`, `$localStorage` and so on.

> You can even share the data between controllers using Factory and
>   Services.

Since you just want the variable to be known throughout the controller. I will be giving you a simple example of using `$sessionStorage`.

In order to use **$sessionStorage** or **$localStorage**, you need to inject **ngStorage**.

First in your `index.html`, include the source:

```
 <script src="https://rawgithub.com/gsklee/ngStorage/master/ngStorage.js"></script>
```

Then in your module definition, inject the `ngStorage`:

```
var app = angular.module('Your App Name', ['ngStorage']);
```

**Your HTTP CALL:**

```
app.controller("exampleCtrl",function($http,user,$sessionStorage){
      user.user_id = data.user_id;
      $sessionStorage.user_id = data.user_id;
      //lets say the user id is 4.
      //and now user.user_id should be 4 as well
})
```

And, in Another `controller` you access it like below:

```
app.controller("nextCtrl",function(user,$sessionStorage){
   console.log($sessionStorage.user_id);
 //gives you 4 which you can then assign to any var you like.
    console.log(user.user_id);
    //gives me 0 which should be 4?
})
```

Following **PLUNKER** demonstrates the use of `factory` and `$sessionStorage` to share data between controllers:
http://plnkr.co/edit/XPHwKQYcSCk3GSilvFtE?p=preview

Comment: Awesome, i did just exactly what i wanted. I will look for more to destroy sessions and unset sessions in this. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Glad I could be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Angular has a module called ngCookies that will allows you to interact with cookies, and it’s simple to use!

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngCookies"]);

ngApp.factory("userPersistenceService", [
"$cookies", function($cookies) {
    var userName = "";

    return {
        setCookieData: function(username) {
            userName = username;
            $cookies.put("userName", username);
        },
        getCookieData: function() {
            userName = $cookies.get("userName");
            return userName;
        },
        clearCookieData: function() {
            userName = "";
            $cookies.remove("userName");
        }
    }
}
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a quick solution, I think you can just store it on the `$rootScope`:
[AngularJS using $rootScope as a data store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16739084/angularjs-using-rootscope-as-a-data-store). (Probably you won't update it very often).

If you don't mind to add a dependency check out this Angular module: https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage. This gives you the best control over your stored data's lifetime: [HTML5 Local storage vs. Session storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523140/html5-local-storage-vs-session-storage)