# How do I store data in local storage using Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

Currently I am using a service to perform an action, namely
retrieve data from the server and then store the data on the server itself.

Instead of this, I want to put the data into local storage instead of storing it on the server.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

this is a bit of my code that stores and retrieves to local storage. i use broadcast events to save and restore the values in the model.

```
app.factory('userService', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {

    var service = {

        model: {
            name: '',
            email: ''
        },

        SaveState: function () {
            sessionStorage.userService = angular.toJson(service.model);
        },

        RestoreState: function () {
            service.model = angular.fromJson(sessionStorage.userService);
        }
    }

    $rootScope.$on("savestate", service.SaveState);
    $rootScope.$on("restorestate", service.RestoreState);

    return service;
}]);
```

Comment: chovy,  here is the complete angular example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940974/maintain-model-of-scope-when-changing-between-views-in-angularjs/16559855#16559855

Comment: For the record ```sessionStorage``` ≠ ```localStorage```

Comment: agreed, the terms do not match, but the spec suggests to me it is stored on the client, which i inferred is what is meant in the original question.  http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: you could use $window.sessionStorage so you can inject it in your tests

Comment: @GuillaumeMassé  what is your recommendation as a w3schools alternative?

Comment: @Anton mozilla has solid documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS3
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript

Comment: what is the lifetime of localStorage ?

Comment: ∞ normally, but may be reset by browsers/extensions

Comment: @GuillaumeMassé I agree, it should be used $window.sessionStorage (localStorage), to allow mocking in testing.

Comment: I don't think that giving an answer for session storage is anyway correct, if one is asking for localstorage.

Answer (score 111):

If you use `$window.localStorage.setItem(key,value)` to store,`$window.localStorage.getItem(key)` to retrieve and `$window.localStorage.removeItem(key)` to remove, then you can access the values in any page.

You have to pass the `$window` service to the controller. Though in JavaScript, `window` object is available globally.

By using `$window.localStorage.xxXX()` the user has control over the `localStorage` value. The size of the data depends upon the browser. If you only use `$localStorage` then value remains as long as you use ***window.location.href*** to navigate to other page and if you use `<a href="location"></a>` to navigate to other page then your `$localStorage` value is lost in the next page.

Comment: This solution suited me best. Why use a plug-in or a module when you can just as easily go straight to the DOM? Because I wanted to store objects rather than simple strings, I just used angular.toJson() in combination with setItem() and angular.fromJson() in combination with getItem(). Easy. Love it.

Comment: This is the best answer. No external dependencies needed.

Comment: Agreed, this is the simplest solution for key/value pair management

Comment: What is key in the line: $window.localStorage.setItem(key,value). Where is it declared and set ?

Comment: The key is whatever you want it to be that uniquely ID's the value. So YOU define the key when you store something and that's the same thing you use to retrieve it.

Comment: Is there some example for this? When I try to use it, I get the following error: https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.9/docs/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=root&p1=%5B$injector:nomod%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.6.9%2F$injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3Droot%0AK%2F%3C@https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.9%2Fangular.min.js:7:76%0ACe%2F%3C%2F%3C%2F%3C@https:%2F

Answer (score 56):

For local storage there is a module for that look at below url:

https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage

and other link for HTML5 local storage and angularJs

http://www.amitavroy.com/justread/content/articles/html5-local-storage-with-angular-js/

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged on StackOverflow as external links tend to die.

Answer (score 50):

Use `ngStorage` For All Your AngularJS Local Storage Needs. Please note that this is NOT a native part of the Angular JS framework.

`ngStorage`  contains two services, `$localStorage` and `$sessionStorage`

```
angular.module('app', [
   'ngStorage'
]).controller('Ctrl', function(
    $scope,
    $localStorage,
    $sessionStorage
){});
```

Check the [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/3vfRkvG7R9DgQxtWbGHz?p=preview&utm_source=angular-js.in&utm_medium=website&utm_campaign=content-curation)

Comment: worth mentionning that is not part of angular, and should be imported as additional file

Comment: link to npm module?

Answer (score 4):

There is one more alternative module which has more activity than `ngStorage`

angular-local-storage:

https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage

Answer (score 2):

I authored (yet another) angular html5 storage service. I wanted to keep the automatic updates made possible by `ngStorage`, but make digest cycles more predictable/intuitive (at least for me), add events to handle when state reloads are required, and also add sharing session storage between tabs. I modelled the API after `$resource` and called it `angular-stored-object`. It can be used as follows:

```
  angular
    .module('auth', ['yaacovCR.storedObject']);

  angular
    .module('auth')
    .factory('session', session);

  function session(ycr$StoredObject) {
    return new ycr$StoredObject('session');
  }
```

API is [here](http://yaacovcr.github.io/angular-stored-object/docs/#/api).

Repo is [here](https://github.com/yaacovCR/angular-stored-object).

Hope it helps somebody!

Comment: Would the down voters care to explain their votes, please?

Comment: I use angular-stored-object in my project now, and it is really easy to use. More over, Yaacov is really quick in answering question. So I do recommend it too !

Answer (score 2):

You can use `localStorage` for the purpose.

**Steps:**

1. add ngStorage.min.js in your file
2. add ngStorage dependency in your module
3. add $localStorage module in your controller
4. use $localStorage.key = value

Answer (score 2):

Follow the steps to store data in Angular - local storage:

1. Add 'ngStorage.js' in your folder.
2. Inject 'ngStorage' in your angular.module

   ```
       eg: angular.module("app", [ 'ngStorage']);
   ```
3. Add `$localStorage` in your app.controller function

4.You can use `$localStorage` inside your controller

```
Eg: $localstorage.login= true;
```

The above will store the localstorage in your browser application

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your needs, like if you want to allow the data to eventually expire or set limitations on how many records to store, you could also look at https://github.com/jmdobry/angular-cache which allows you to define if the cache sits in memory, localStorage, or sessionStorage.

Answer (score 1):

One should use a third party script for this called called ngStorage here is a example how to use.It updates localstorage with change in scope/view.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <!-- CDN Link -->
    <!--https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ngStorage/0.3.6/ngStorage.min.js-->
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="ngStorage.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('app', ['ngStorage']);
        app.factory("myfactory", function() {
            return {
                data: ["ram", "shyam"]
            };
        })
        app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $localStorage, $sessionStorage, myfactory) {

            $scope.abcd = $localStorage; //Pass $localStorage (or $sessionStorage) by reference to a hook under $scope
            // Delete from Local Storage
            //delete $scope.abcd.counter;
            // delete $localStorage.counter;
            // $localStorage.$reset(); // clear the localstorage
            /* $localStorage.$reset({
                 counter: 42   // reset with default value
             });*/
            // $scope.abcd.mydata=myfactory.data;
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">

    <button ng-click="abcd.counter = abcd.counter + 1">{{abcd.counter}}</button>
</body>

</html>
```