# Remember angular toggle state after page refresh without js cookies

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I've got two sections that are being shown and hidden using angular. After filling few fields, I need to validate the data server-side, and refresh the page - then, div's with ng-show / ng-hide directives are losing their memory. I saw a solution for that problem using js cookies, but I think it's not a good practice for my problem. Is there something to remember that another way, or should I do this with cookies?

Comment: You can use [session storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retain page data on refreshing the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24033696/retain-page-data-on-refreshing-the-page)