# How to keep a json in memory or cache with angularjs?

Tags: json, angularjs, rest

I have a angularjs app which reads json from java when the user is logged in:

```
$http({ method: 'POST', url: 'ws/login/user', data : user, cache: true })
.success(function (response) {                                                    
    $rootScope.userInfo = response; // Here I get the json                                          
    response = { success : true };                    
    callback(response);
}).error(function (response) {
    response = { success : false };
    response.message = 'Error.';
    callback(response);
});
```

Everything works fine until I press F5, then the JSON disappears.

How can I keep the data between page loads?

Comment: Java or JavaScript? The two are totally different.

Comment: The backend is developed in Java. I'm using RESTful service to get the json.

Comment: Why is the application in need of a hard refresh in the first place?

Comment: Is not necessary for the application. Is just to prevent accidental refresh by users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use cookies or [Local Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API). A quick google search shows this library: https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've solved using LocalStorage! It's really useful, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Modern web applications will use local storage to keep data between page loads. Here is a helpful answer to get you started.

[How do I store data in local storage using Angularjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18247130/how-to-store-the-data-to-local-storage)