# Saving controller state when html page is closed and restore again in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, state

It is possible to save state of a controller when html page is closed and restore the state again when the page is open in AngularJs? If yes can you give me an example?
Thank you!

Comment: It should be theoretically possible using cookies or localstorage, but **you** should give **us** an example of what you tried, and we'll try helping with the code :)

Comment: I've been using this library with much success: https://github.com/agrublev/angularLocalStorage it handles session persistance through local storage with cookie fallback.

Comment: Thanks both of you! I'll try to make something on my own :)

Comment: any progress? if you solved your problem, post a basic solution to help others out! :)

Comment: Hello guys! Sorry for the soooo late answer. I was off for more than a year. I managed to save the controller state at an end. I used local storage feature (see the post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18247130/how-do-i-store-data-in-local-storage-using-angularjs). It fit my needs then an it was simple to use.