# How to store array from on-click and use it in dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I have an HTML page that has an option for drag-n-drop and a "Preview" button. I want to call a function on the `click` event of that button, which will fetch all the files that are dragged onto the page. When I press this button, it opens a `<px-modal>` (a popup which displays some data), and it has a dropdown (`<paper-dropdown>` and `<paper-item>`), which should display the filename fetched earlier.

So I have the data, but I don't know how to store it or display it as dropdown content.

I have tried the `<template>` tag, but it fires on page-load when I need it to fire after the files are dropped onto the page. Otherwise, the data is `null`.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Without some code to look at, it's hard to help you but in general, my advice will be to use a service to store your data and all your directive/controller that needs to have access to the data should havce a dependency on this service.

Have a look at option 1 on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31626360/angularjs-best-pratice-for-data-store)

If that's not what you're looking for, post more details, create a jsFiddle to show us where you are so we can help you better.

Comment: The linked answer is an Angular-specific solution, but the OP is using only Polymer.