# Passing data from one route to another route

Tags: angularjs

It must be able to pass data between route controllers. Like for example have an input field in one route where its contents will be displayed in the next route. I don't want it with `$rootScope`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = "John Doe";
});
</script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
Name: <input ng-model="name">
<h1>You entered: {{name}}</h1>

<a href="">Click to see this data to another page (route)</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Write down a service for sharing data between controllers.

Comment: How can i do that? i am not getting it. can you help me ?

Comment: How does the app change routes? Is this a SPA (Single-Page Application)? Or does it do a full page re-load to change routes? As written, the question is too broad.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angularjs Best Practice for Data Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31626360/angularjs-best-practice-for-data-store)

Answer (score 1):

### See This

[RipTutorial -
Handling session storage through service using angularjs](https://riptutorial.com/angularjs/example/26354/handling-session-storage-through-service-using-angularjs)

```
app.factory('storageService', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {

    return {
        get: function(key) {
            return sessionStorage.getItem(key);
        },
        save: function(key, data) {
            sessionStorage.setItem(key, data);
        }
    };
}]);

app.controller('myCtrl',['storageService',function(storageService) {

  // Save session data to storageService
  storageService.save('key', 'value');

  // Get saved session data from storageService
  var sessionData = storageService.get('key');

});
```

Comment: Thanks but i couldnt do that yet