# Error: Unspecified error. when adding a localStorage.setItem in angular js

Tags: angularjs, local-storage

Im getting following error when I add localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
line to the controller.

> Error: Unspecified error.    at $scope.singleSg
>   (file:///C:/ashwitha%20G%20S/sugg/js/controller.js:28:21)    at fn
>   (Function code:2:296)    at expensiveCheckFn
>   (file:///C:/ashwitha%20G%20S/sugg/lib/angular.js:15906:11)    at
>   callback (file:///C:/ashwitha%20G%20S/sugg/lib/angular.js:25885:17)
>   at Scope.prototype.$eval
>   (file:///C:/ashwitha%20G%20S/sugg/lib/angular.js:17682:9)    at
>   Scope.prototype.$apply
>   (file:///C:/ashwitha%20G%20S/sugg/lib/angular.js:17782:13)    at
>   Anonymous function
>   (file:///C:/ashwitha%20G%20S/sugg/lib/angular.js:25890:17)    at
>   n.event.dispatch
>   (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js:3:12312)
>   at r.handle
>   (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js:3:9090)

```
.controller('sgController', function ($scope, $state, loginOperation) {

    loginOperation.suggestion().success(function (recData) {
        if (recData) {
                //console.log(recData);
            $scope.suggestions = recData;
            $scope.singleSg = function (index) {
                console.log(index);
                localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
                $state.go('sugRm');
            }
        }
    }).error(function () {
        console.log("Request failed");
        });


})
```

Comment: Have you injected localstorage service into your controller and missed that in here? How are you getting localstorage? See the implementation in details at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32486871/angularjs-use-local-storage

Comment: Its ok if im able to do this 
localStorage.setItem("lastname", index);
but I'm not able to add anything here

Comment: Do you mean that you are able to do `localStorage.setItem("lastname",index)` but nothing else?

Comment: Im not able to add anything

Comment: I want to add this `localStorage.setItem("lastname",index)`

Comment: Looks like issue with the localStorage service, if you refer the link in my comment, you will see two ways to get the localStorage, one is to get it from $window, but then you will have to configure it everytime, whereas second approach looks better, you need to set it once and then pass it everywhere as a service. Refer the accepted answer.

Comment: Tried with `window.localStorage.setItem('key', 'value' );` method, it gives the same error.  I just want to save the index value to local storage and route to other state. If I comment this line `localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
` it is routing to the state (`$state.go('sugRm');`)

Comment: Can you create a Plunker(https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) or something and show your code?

Comment: Your code from github works for me. I don't see any error in console other than issue with favicon.ico. What browser are you using? I tried it on Chrome Version 70.0.3538.110 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Check the ReadMe.MD of your repo.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0, hope you checked suggestion page and clicked read more.

Comment: It works for me on Edge(Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0)  as well, on my local environment I went to the Suggestion page, there I can see the list of items. Clicked on "Read More" button and saw the details of that item. When I click on an item, I can see the id of that item against "lastname" in the local storage, and it get overwritten when I click on something else. I think you have issue somewhere else.

Comment: when i click on the read more, index is getting printed in console, then I'm getting that error.

Answer (score 0):

```
.controller('sgController', function ($scope, $state,$localStorage,loginOperation) {

loginOperation.suggestion().success(function (recData) {
    if (recData) {
            //console.log(recData);
        $scope.suggestions = recData;
        $scope.singleSg = function (index) {
            console.log(index);
            $localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
            $state.go('sugRm');
        }
    }
}).error(function () {
    console.log("Request failed");
    });
```

})

use ***$localStorage*** as parameter in controller Function then only You get localstorage Object.

Comment: Im not passing it from anywhere!

Comment: I just want to store the value `localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");` smith in a variable lastname in local Storage or session storage

Comment: with out passing how controller knows about localstorage.then compile time it gives error  unknown function  unable to proceced.