# Where is the user info stored in http authentication method?

Tags: java, http, authentication

It maybe different for different http authentication. But just want to know where is it stored (blog post would be helpful). In java servlet, I can get the userinfo from request.getRemoteUser(), then is the user info stored in http header or cookie. And how does the client specify that. e.g. In java I can construct URI with user info, but where is it stored. Any related blog post would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question well enough, you're trying to figure it out how the client side information related to the user are stored .. well.. It depends of the client implementation you are using I guess .

For instance Angular can use different kind of user information storage methods like [CacheFactory](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory) or LocalStorage API as mentionned in [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18247130/how-to-store-the-data-to-local-storage).

Comment: Now I have one server framework which provide authentication method, then how can I use interact with it using client . Is is framework specific or there's some standard ?

Comment: The only standard comes from Java Servlet. An authenticated client can access the [User Principal](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getUserPrincipal%28%29) and the [remote user](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRemoteUser%28%29)

Comment: This is for server side, then for client side, how can I construct my request to meet this standard ?