# how to update a $scope object value in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following:

sample collection of objects

```
var myObjects = [
    { name: "Object1", shape: "circle", color: "red" },
    { name: "Object2", shape: "square", color: "orange" },
    { name: "Object3", shape: "triangle", color: "yellow" },
    { name: "Object4", shape: "circle", color: "green" },
    { name: "Object5", shape: "sphere", color: "blue" },
    { name: "Object6", shape: "hexagon", color: "indigo" },
    { name: "Object7", shape: "square", color: "violet" }
];
```

I get an array of just the objects matching specific criteria.return an array with only red objects

```
var myRedObjects = $filter('filter')(myObjects, { color: "red" });
```

Now my problem is that how I can update filter object name in array myObjects.

Comment: I can't get what you want to do: you need to change the value of the property "name" of your array?

Comment: Yes i want to change the myObject Array name That have the red color

Comment: But i want to update it after Filter result i got match

Comment: When you use `filter`, it will return a new array and references of object. You  can manually loop over array and set if matching value is found

Comment: bro i want to know any way here now how i can update if filter have the object then update the upper myObjects.name = 'any name'

Comment: @MuhammadirfanMayo If I understand, you are trying to fetch objects based on a filter criteria and wish to update name in those objects. Question is do you wish to update original array or create a copy of filtered objects and have temporary update in them? Also, if you wish to tag someone, use `@` followed by his name in comment.

Answer (score 0):

Change your filter usage to this:

```
var myRedObjects = $filter('filter')(myObjects, { color: "red" }).map(function(currentObject){
   currentObject.name = "myNewName",
}
```

`map` will iterate your filtered array (much like a foreach) and will let you change the name of the current iterated object.

Bear in mind that `map` it's compatible with all browser from IE <= 9. If you are targeting older browser, you'll need to add a polyfill or not use map at all (a simple `for` will do the work).
You can find more on map function [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Comment: are you saying on the currentObject place i can put myObjects? variable

Comment: currentObject is a single iterated element of your myObjects array.

Comment: Yup it's working Good bro thanks for this help. i need one more help bro i want to save this myObjects into local storage via angular can i do it? mean complete object i want to use

Comment: Follow this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18247130/how-do-i-store-data-in-local-storage-using-angularjs
Remember to accept the answer if your issue is solved

Comment: Briefly, to save: sessionStorage.setItem('key', angular.toJson(myObject));
And to retrieve: var object = angular.fromJson(sessionStorage.getItem('key'));

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var myObjects = [
{ name: "Object1", shape: "circle", color: "red" },
{ name: "Object2", shape: "square", color: "orange" },
{ name: "Object3", shape: "triangle", color: "yellow" },
{ name: "Object4", shape: "circle", color: "green" },
{ name: "Object5", shape: "sphere", color: "blue" },
{ name: "Object6", shape: "hexagon", color: "indigo" },
{ name: "Object7", shape: "square", color: "violet" }
];

var myRedObjects = $filter('filter')(myObjects, { color: "red" });

myRedObjects = myRedObjects[0].name= "RedObjectNewName";
```

Comment: sambath Kumar s thanks to reply but Luxor001 solution meet my requirements any how thank u.

Answer (score 0):

**$filter** gives you the filtered elements by reference, so you can update the members of **$filter('filter')(myObjects, { color: "red" })** directly and it would make changes in **myObjects** variable.

Try following code:

```
var myRedObjects = $filter('filter')(myObjects, { color: "red" });
for (var index in myRedObjects) {
    myRedObjects[index].name = 'newName';
}
```

Or, if you are using *underscore.js*, then:

```
_.each(
    $filter('filter')(myObjects, { color: "red" }),
    function(item){
        item.name = 'newName';
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var myObjects = [
            { name: "Object1", shape: "circle", color: "red" },
            { name: "Object2", shape: "square", color: "orange" },
            { name: "Object3", shape: "triangle", color: "yellow" },
            { name: "Object4", shape: "circle", color: "green" },
            { name: "Object5", shape: "sphere", color: "blue" },
            { name: "Object6", shape: "hexagon", color: "indigo" },
            { name: "Object7", shape: "square", color: "violet" }
        ];

        var myRedObjects = $filter('filter')(myObjects, { color: "red" }); 
        // filter returns Array so
        myRedObjects.forEach(function(Obj) {
            var idx = myObjects.indexOf(obj);
            myObjects[idx].name = "Update name";
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Luxor001 answer is right. it's i required and working nice basically i want to change the name of original value not filter array value and with the help of Map it's working cool.

```
var myRedObjects = $filter('filter')(myObjects, { color: "red" }).map(function(currentObject){
   currentObject.name = "myNewName",
}
```