# Session management angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am looking for a way to set session and retrieve a session in angular js. I do have an idea in PHP which was

```
$_SESSION['username'] = "xyz";
```

but I can't a way in angular. can someone please give me a link to any documents or a small snippet?

Thanx.

Comment: Are you using Angular1.x or Angular2+ ?

Comment: I am using angular1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a service as mentioned under following post to access local storage and can store the data there:

[How do I store data in local storage using Angularjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18247130/how-do-i-store-data-in-local-storage-using-angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

Please go through this http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/jj12345678910/a-simple-localstorage-demo-using-angularjs-and-html-5/

This may be help you.