# Save image file in local storage and retrieve image from file path html angularjs

Tags: javascript, caching

Have a question similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42481771/upload-image-feature-and-save-in-local-storage-using-angularjs).

How do you save and load an image to and from `localStorage`, a personalized cache, using plain JavaScript?

Comment: Have you tried anything by yourself? Maybe create a variable, assign the file object to it and set it in local storage, get the variable from the local storage when required. As simple as asking how [local storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18247130/how-do-i-store-data-in-local-storage-using-angularjs) works.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I am able to store data sucessfully and get it back too. I am facing an issue with the Image storage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For storing and retrieving image from local storage you can simply use javascript. Here is an example:

```
    bannerImage = document.getElementById('bannerImg');
    imgData = getBase64Image(bannerImage);
    localStorage.setItem("imgData", imgData);

    function getBase64Image(img) {
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;

        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

        return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
}
```

[Here is the link to the StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183180/how-to-save-an-image-to-localstorage-and-display-it-on-the-next-page)

Comment: Thank you @Naveed, I tried this but I am getting an error "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLImageElement or SVGImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas)'". Shoul I add something to my project ? I am using angularjs without npm or bower.

Answer (score 1):

[this post](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/02/saving-images-and-files-in-localstorage/) talks about saving image in the local storage.