# angular is not able to get the the service when refresh is pressed

Tags: angularjs

My code is as shown below:

```
angular.module('xyz.homeController', [])
    .controller('homeController', ['homeService', '$scope', '$location', '$modal', '$rootScope', '$localstorage', '$window', 'GoogleSignin'
        function(homeService, $scope, $location, $modal, $rootScope, $localstorage, $window, GoogleSignin) {

])




angular.module('xyz.homeService', [])
    .factory('homeService', function() {
        var data = {};
        var deliveryOption = 0;
        var payCardOption = 0;
        var orderId = '';
        var restaurentID = '';
        var orderInfo = {};
        var orderItems = [];

        data.setDeliveryOption = function(info) {
            this.deliveryOption = info;
        };

        data.getDeliveryOption = function() {
            return this.deliveryOption;
        };

        data.setOrderId = function(orderId) {
            this.orderId = orderId;
        };

        data.getOrderId = function() {
            return this.orderId;
        };

        data.setRestaurentId = function(id) {
            this.restaurentID = id;
        };

        data.getRestaurentID = function() {
            return this.restaurentID;
        };

        data.setOrderInfo = function(info) {
            this.orderInfo = info;
        };

        data.getOrderInfo = function() {
            return this.orderInfo;
        };

        data.setOrderItems = function(items) {
            this.orderItems = items;
        };

        data.getOrderItems = function() {
            return this.orderItems;
        };

        data.setPayCardOption = function(payCardOption) {
            this.payCardOption = payCardOption;
        };

        data.getPayCardOption = function() {
            return this.payCardOption;
        };

        return data;
    });
```

Now when refresh is pressed , the route is called perfectly, I have handlede the information inside the route perfectly, but somehow I am not able to restore the state of app and as a result of that, I am not able to use `homeService` perfectly, how to get the reference of `homeService` perfectly, so that I can use it?

Comment: you you possibly [asking the wrong question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) since you said: "_I am not able to restore the state of app_". What is your service doing in the first place?

Comment: **perfectly** means, whats happening now, any error?

Comment: @Sravan I am not able to hold the data inside service when the page is refreshed

Comment: Please paste the service code.

Comment: @MrugeshThaker consider using `localStorage` to save the data even after the page refresh

Comment: @Sravan I have posted the service code.

Comment: In question you asked about `homeService` and you added someother service

Comment: @Sravan I have updated code for `homeService`

Comment: Your module is different?

Comment: @Sravan yes it is different

Comment: @MrugeshThaker Services are non persistant. You need to store the data in localStorage or similar.

Comment: You can use ngStorage module to store your data check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/28853374/4711957

Comment: Your service will be called when you refresh, but for data, you need to either store in `localStorage`, or should make a backend call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term you're looking for is *singleton*.

[All services in AngularJs are singletons](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) but you are using *factory* which is initialized by controller.

This will solve your problem if you're swithcing from one controller to the other.

However if you're refreshing the page, the application will reboot.
There's no way around it than using localstorage, sessionstorage, cookies...etc.

These are available through the [$window](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window) service.