# Is there a way to show previously selected option in a dropdown

Tags: html, angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-select

I have a `<select>` element in my html page. The `<option>`s are given through a  loop. The selected value is stored using a `ng-model`. This data is now push to a database. The next time that page reloads I would like the the  `<select>` field to hold the previously selected option. Is there anyway to do it?

I have seen that `ng-model` generally fills text fields on it own. I tried to do the same with `<select>`-`<option>` but it doesn't work

---

```
<select ng-model="option">
  <option value = "" disabled selected>---Choose an Option--</option> 
  <option ng-repeat = "x in option" value="x">{{x}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Feel free to show the tried code!

Comment: AS you said the selected data is pushed to the database then you need to retrieve the data from the db when you do a reload a initialise your ng-model variable with that

Comment: <select ng-model="option">
    <option value = "" disabled selected>---Choose an Option--</option>
    <option ng-repeat = "x in option" value="x">{{x}}</option>
</select>

Comment: you need to use a service/data store  for this, where you can store a value and get it back on page-refresh

Comment: Can you please share some sample code of ts file?

Comment: I am able to get the value. My problem is not being able to display the previously selected value

Comment: @HarishPrabhu Up to when you want to store the previously selected value? i.e Save for 2 hrs, Save for 2 days? etc

Comment: The option selected is to be stored forever. The page can be accessed many times. So every time the page is visited, I want to show the selected value instead of the user having to re-select every time they visit

Comment: You could use sessionStorage for a case like this (or local storage if you want it to be more persistent). 
Something like this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vprkkh

Comment: I am using angualrjs, as far as I know I don't think it supports typescript. Am I wrong? @Jojofoulk

Comment: @HarishPrabhu See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18247130/how-do-i-store-data-in-local-storage-using-angularjs)

Comment: Thank you guys for all the effort. I had made an error else where. I am so sorry I did respond earlier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When selecting from an array of primitives, use the `ng-options` directive:

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.options=["hello","world",1,2,3];

    //set previously selected option
    $scope.option = "world";
    
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <select ng-model="option" ng-options="item for item in options">
         <option value = "">---Choose an Option--</option> 
    </select>
    <br>selected={{option}}
<body>
```

One can select using `ng-repeat` with an array of objects, but not with an array of primitives. Under the hood, the `<select>` directive annotates each option with tracking information. It can't annotate primitives.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS `<select>` Directive API Reference - Choosing between `ng-repeat` and `ng-options`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#choosing-between-ngrepeat-and-ngoptions-)

Comment: Thank You man. I had made a error in the flow of my program which caused the error. I am so sorry that I hadn't responded earlier. Appreciate the effort