# passing array from from view to another with angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a view contain this form, I need to display this new user after clicking the save button on another page/view in the HTML table. Any help, please!

```
 <form ng-submit="adduser()">
            <label class="lbl" >First name:</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="newuser.fName"><br>

            <label class="lbl" >Last name:</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="newuser.lName"><br>

            <label class="lbl" >Age:</label>
            <input type="number" ng-model="newuser.age"><br>

            <label class="lbl" >Gender:</label><br>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" ng-model="newuser.selectVal"><label >Male</label>      <input type="radio" name="gender" id="fml" value="Female" ng-model="newuser.selectVal"><label>Female</label><br>

            <label class="lbl" >About user:</label><br>
            <textarea ng-model="newuser.about" id="txtarea" ng-model="newuser.about"></textarea><br>


            <button type="submit">Save</button>
            <button id="clear">Clear all</button>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the user data in next router page, You can take help of [AngularJS service](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_services.asp) and [AngularJS Factory](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/angularjs-factory-method/) By using them you can pass the data one page to another page

But

If you want to show the data that is completly next browser Tab then you can use [$sessionStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_sessionstorage.asp) and $localStorage in angular

Also check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18247130/how-do-i-store-data-in-local-storage-using-angularjs)