# angular <back> that preserves state

Tags: angularjs

I have 2 angular pages

Load page 1 which shows a big table of stuff, set some filters to find what you want, click the row in the table to get more details (loads page 2 which provides details).

From page 2, Press back button, page 1 loads from scratch, without the filter the user entered

Is there a way to preserve the filter the user has set when he goes back to page1?  Is there a way I can keep the table where it was (e.g., if the user has scrolled halfway down, it returns where he was, rather than to the top of the table)

I could do this manually (pass the filter to the details page, then pass it back when user hits  and scroll him back to where he was in the table), but this feels painful.

Comment: when you say "Page" do you mean to an angular route ?

Comment: Yeah, an angular route.  sorry for being vague.

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940974/maintain-model-of-scope-when-changing-between-views-in-angularjs