# AngularJS - How to keep the scope variables live even after going to another state and coming back?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I my angular app, I have a list of items shown in one page and on clicking continue button, the app will move to another `state`. In that page there is a "Back" button which has the code `$state.go('prevPage')` on `ng-click` event. But on coming back all the data are cleared. Is there any way I can keep the scope variables alive on returning back ?

**Update** 
What I tried..

On going to another state, saved all the scope data in a service

```
returnItemModel.saveReturnData($scope);
```

While coming back retrived it and assigned it to scope and I call the digest cycle.

```
var savedReturnData = returnItemModel.restoreReturnData();
if(savedReturnData){ 
    $scope = savedReturnData;
    $scope.$apply();
}
```

This is not working. Does someone know the reason.

Comment: You can store your data in a service/factory.

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940974/maintain-model-of-scope-when-changing-between-views-in-angularjs

Answer (score 1):

The scope values get destroyed upon routing to another state. You can use angular services like `service`, `factory`, or `values` to persist value when the scope is destroyed. This can done using setting a listener for destroy event in controller.

```
$scope.$on("destroy", function(){
  // data to keep alive
});
```

**Update**

you cannot do like this: `$scope = savedReturnData;`. You have to do somthing like this. `$scope.prevScope = savedReturnData`. And then you can use the previous scope in you view like `{{ prevScope.someVar }}`

Comment: Its not working. Actually, its not just one or two variables. there are a number of vata associated to that scope. I want all of them like how they were before. That is why I took this approach.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put those values in either service or factory as scope values gets destroyed upon moving to another state.